# Google App Engine instance being restarted

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a java app deployed to GCP App Engine with a jar. I tested with a load testing framework to generate steady state 100 QPS of traffic. I have also set the maximum instance count to 1. I am following the automatic scaling.

When I go to "instances" page, it says "This instance is being restarted" all the time. But all requests are succeeding.

1. Why is the instance being restarted while serving requests?
2. How do I know the cause for this restart?

Comment: A common reason for restart is when an instance exceeds memory. Figure out the amount of memory being consumed by your App and make sure your instance class meets/exceeds that - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes

Comment: In addition check the logs, I'm almost sure something is there.